# Proper anchor placement

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome

I want to direct link to part of page with:

```
<a href="AnotherPage.html#name">Link Text</a>
```

To link with:

```
AnotherPage.html#name
```

But Google Chrome links it to

```
AnotherPage.html/#name
```

Is there any validation rules here? Why there's a difference here?

Comment: Can you share the full code? I've never seen Chrome behave in this manner. Do you have some htaccess rewrites in place to add a trailing slash or somesuch on your server?

Comment: Nope its plain html file with just one line `<a href="AnotherPage.html#name">Link Text</a>` as provided. So which one is correct: `.html#name` or `.html/#name` ?